# Dealing nested transactions using NHibernate in Sharp Architecture

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I would like to know how to deal with nested transactions e.g. Between
one begin and commit, I have another begin and commit. The reason I am
asking you is because in my ApplicationServices project I have
services that depends on other services. And a method of a parent
service begins a transaction and depending upon some logic, it might
have to call one of the methods of the dependent child services, that
also in turn perform begin and commit. The Child services method are
also being used independently as well directly from the controllers,
therefore I have to use begin and commit in the child services.

So in short, basically I will end up having something like this

```
   using( Repository1.DbContext.BeginTransaction() )
   {
      try
      {
         .....
         .....
         using( Repository2.DbContext.BeginTransaction() )
         {
            try
            {
               .....
               .....
               Repository2.DbContext.CommitTransaction()
            }
            catch
            {
               Repository2.DbContext.RollBack();
               throw;
            }
        }
        Repository1.DbContext.CommitTransaction()
      }
      catch
      {
         Repository1.DbContext.RollBack();
         throw;
      }
   }
```

So there are nested begins and commits. I would like to know

-what would be the behavior, when the nested Repository2 gets
committed successfully but the parent Repository1 is rollbacked ?

How can I control this behavior in code e.g.

-if I don't want to make child transaction part of the parent
transaction.
-how to figure out wether a transaction is already running before
creating a child transaction

or if there is another elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks
Nabeel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate does not support nested transactions. Is the DbContext is the same for both Repository1 and Repository2? If that's the case then they can participate in the same transaction. If not, you'll have to split the transactions into two methods or look at the [System.Transactions namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.aspx).

Comment: Yes the DBContect is the same for both repositories and after profiling in NHibernate Profiler, it turns out that nhibernate does not begin a new transaction for inner repository.

And yes splitting the transaction into two methods, thats exactly what I am doing it at the moment. But I thought there might be a better way of doing this. I have used TransactionScope in the past, so I am thinking to try that as I am using a single SQL 2005 database in my application.

Comment: I found this another post on SO to be useful as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646318/nhibernate-with-transactionscope

Answer (score 0):

If you place your transaction boundaries at your controllers level then I would say you don't need nested transactions.

Comment: well there is a winform client as well. And I am thinking to keep the transaction management code inside my ApplicationServices project instead of Controllers project, that way I won't have to manage the transaction manipulation code in Winform again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the UnitOfWork attribute in the Sharp-Architecture-Contrib project?

http://github.com/codai/Sharp-Architecture-Contrib

http://tomcabanski.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E0D3617496209F45!220.entry

http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/ContribConfiguration.ashx

http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/ContribUnitOfWork.ashx

Comment: Interesting! I will look into contrib. Thanks Dan